# java regex: capitalize words with certain number of characters

Tags: java, regex, string, character

I am trying to capitalize the words in a string with more than 5 characters.

I was able to retrieve the number of words that are greater 5 characters using .length, and I could exclude the words that were greater than 5 characters but I couldn't capitalize them.

Ex. input: "i love eating pie"

Ex. output: "i love Eating pie"

Here's my code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sentence = "";
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a sentence: ");
    sentence = input.nextLine();
    String[] myString = sentence.split("\\s\\w{6,}".toUpperCase());
     for (String myStrings : myString) {
         System.out.println(sentence);
         System.out.println(myStrings);
         }
```

Comment: You could do a find and replace with a callback. `"(?<!\\S)([a-z])(\\w{5})"` Replace capture group 1 (to upper) + capture group 2.

Comment: Edit: I tried using replace all and now I can capitalize any word thats greater than 5 characters but I want to capitalize just the first letter           String myString = sentence.replaceAll("\\b\\w{1,6}\\b\\s?", "").toUpperCase();
    System.out.println(sentence);
    System.out.println(myString);

Comment: For fixed number of chars its `\w{num}`. My regex only matches the first part of the word with a fixed minimum num of chars, no need to match the whole thing. It also just finds words that start with lower cased letters, if you just want to replace the first letter, etc .. And `(?<!\S)` is a typical space word-style boundary that also matches the begging of string (like `\b` does).

Comment: I just added substring and it worked  thanks                                                        String myString = sentence.replaceAll("\\b\\w{1,6}\\b\\s?", "");
  String=myString.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+myString.substring(1);
    System.out.println(sentence);
    System.out.println(upper);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String sentence = "";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(sentence.length());
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter a sentence: ");
sentence = input.nextLine();
/*
 * \\s (match whitespace character)
 * (<?g1> (named group with name g1)
 * \\w{6,}) (match word of length 6) (end of g1)
 * | (or)
 * (?<g2> (named group with name g2)
 * \\S+) (match any non-whitespace characters) (end of g2)
 */
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s(?<g1>\\w{6,})|(?<g2>\\S+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sentence);

//check if the matcher found a match
while (matcher.find())
{
    //get value from g1 group (null if not found)
    String g1 = matcher.group("g1");
    //get value from g2 group (null if not found)
    String g2 = matcher.group("g2");

    //if g1 is not null and is not an empty string
    if (g1 != null && g1.length() > 0)
    {
        //get the first character of this word and upercase it then append it to the StringBuilder
        sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(g1.charAt(0)));
        //sanity check to stop us from getting IndexOutOfBoundsException
        //check if g1 length is more than 1 and append the rest of the word to the StringBuilder
        if(g1.length() > 1) sb.append(g1.substring(1, g1.length()));
        //append a space
        sb.append(" ");
    }
    //we only need to check if g2 is not null here
    if (g2 != null)
    {
        //g2 is smaller than 5 characters so just append it to the StringBuilder
        sb.append(g2);
        //append a space
        sb.append(" ");
    }
}
System.out.println("Original Sentence: " + sentence);
System.out.println("Modified Sentence: " + sb.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me understand it a lot more

Comment: I know replaceAll will remove the words less than 5 characters but is there any other method that will keep the words which are less than 5 char and capitalize the ones  greater than 5 char. This is what I have :                                       String myString = sentence.replaceAll("\\b\\w{1,6}\\b\\s?", "");
  String=myString.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+myString.substring(1);
    System.out.println(sentence);
    System.out.println(upper);

Comment: If there's no simpler way I'll use the pattern and matcher

Comment: there is no simple solution that I know of to doing that but I can edit my answer for an alternative

Answer (score 1):

Split input sentence with space as delimiter and use intiCap method if length greater than 5:

PS: System.out.print to be replaced with StringBuilder.

```
String delim = " ";
String[] myString = sentence.split(delim);

for (int i = 0; i < myString.length; i++) {
    if (i != 0) System.out.print(delim);

    if (myString[i].length() > 5)
        System.out.print(intiCap(myString[i]));
    else
        System.out.print(myString[i]);
}


private static String intiCap(String string) {
    return Character.toUpperCase(string.charAt(0)) + string.substring(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I figured it out but your way is a nice alternative too

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following (short and sweet :P):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?=\\b\\w{6,})([a-z])\\w+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(sentence);
StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()){
    m.appendReplacement(s, m.group(1).toUpperCase() + m.group(0).substring(1));
}
System.out.println(s.toString());
```

See [Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/fkgR94)